# How to create a table in mysql and update the post meta table for example sku row, price, stock

Tags: php, mysql

The post meta table contains the specifications of database products.
Now I want to update database three attributes of sku , price, stock per post_id.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPUCU.jpg)
Now I'm going to write a query to convert these three row items into columns.
This is the wrong query I wrote .

```
SELECT `meta_value`"sku" FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_key`='_sku'
AND
SELECT `meta_value`"price" FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_key`='_price'
AND
SELECT `meta_value`"stock" FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_key`='_stock'
```

Comment: What's columns of new table you want to create ?

Comment: [Start with the manual on UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html).

Comment: The columns of the new table I want to create are:
sku. price. stock

Answer (score 0):

There are two query methods
The first method is as follows:

```
SELECT
   wp_postmeta.post_id,
   wp_postmeta.meta_key,
   wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_sku'
OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock'
OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_price'
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.post_id
```

The second method is as follows:

```
SELECT post_id,
                 MAX (CASE WHEN meta_key = '_sku' THEN meta_value END) as sku,
                 MAX (CASE WHEN meta_key = '_price' THEN meta_value END) as price,
                 MAX (CASE WHEN meta_key = '_stock' THEN meta_value END) as stock
                
                 FROM wp_postmeta
                 Group by post_id
```